# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'ContextProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

I am trying to render some card item conditionally by the status. I am in a nextjs 13 proyect build like a 12 one.

The typescript version is: "5.2.2"

Its throwing that error and I don't understand why: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'ContextProps'.

Btw... I am pretty new to Typescript and i am currently learning it.

The code is this:

EntryContext.tsx:

```
import { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from 'react';
import { entriesReducer } from './';
import { Entry } from '../../interfaces';
import { generateId } from '../../utils';

export type ContextProps = {
  entries: Entry[]
}

export type EntriesState = {
  entries: Entry[]
}

const ENTRIES_INITIAL_STATE: EntriesState = {
  entries: [
    {
      _id: generateId(),
      description: 'Esto es una prueba',
      createdAt: Date.now().toString(),
      status: 'Pending'
    },
    {
      _id: generateId(),
      description: 'Esto es una prueba',
        createdAt: (Date.now() - 10000).toString(),
        status: 'In-progress'
      },
      {
        _id: generateId(),
        description: 'Esto es una prueba',
        createdAt: (Date.now() - 100000).toString(), 
      status: 'Finished'
    },
  ]
}

export const EntriesContext = createContext<ContextProps>({
  entries: []
})

export const EntriesProvider = (
  { 
    children 
}: { 
    children: React.ReactNode 
}): JSX.Element => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(entriesReducer, ENTRIES_INITIAL_STATE)

  return (
    <EntriesContext.Provider value={{
      ...state
    }}>
      {children}
    </EntriesContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useEntries = () => useContext(EntriesContext)
```

The problem is here, in the renderEntries constant

EntryList.tsx:

```
import { List, Paper } from "@mui/material"
import { EntryCard } from "./EntryCard"
import { Entry, Status } from "../../interfaces"
import { useEntries } from "../../context/entries"

type Props = {
  status: Status
}

export const EntryList = ({ status }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const entries = useEntries()

  const renderEntries = entries
    .filter((entry: Entry) => entry.status === status)
    .map((entry: Entry) => (
      <EntryCard
        key={entry._id}
        entry={entry}
      />
    ))
  return (
    <div

    >
      <Paper
        sx={{
          height: 'calc(100vh - 160px)',
          overflowY: 'auto',
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          padding: 1,
        }}
      >
        <List
          sx={{
            opacity: 1
          }}
        >

        </List>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context is an object with `entries` prop

```
export const EntriesContext = createContext<ContextProps>({
  entries: []
})
```

When You write `const entries = useEntries()`.
The `entries` type is `{entries: []}` and you can't filter object (❌ `entries.filter`).

### You can solve that by:

1. destructure entries from the context

```
const {entries} = useEntries()
```

2. 

```
const entries = useEntries()

const renderEntries = entries.entries
    .filter((entry: Entry) => entry.status === status)
    .map((entry: Entry) => (
      <EntryCard
        key={entry._id}
        entry={entry}
      />
    ))
```

3. structure in the hook

```
export const useEntries = () => {
  const ctx = useContext(EntriesContext)
  return ctx.entries
}
```

4. pass array instead of object to the context

```
const EntriesContext = createContext([])
```

Comment: Right, I try the first solution and work just fine! Thanks so much.